# I want to add data to my table using ORM in python

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to add data in my database using ORM, and i am new to ORM in python. I am confused in SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy."I tried this but don't know how to proceed further

---

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.db')
Base = declarative_base()

class Student(Base):
    __tablename__='Student'
    name=Column(String)
    seq=Column(Integer)
    
    def __init__(self,name,sequence):
        self.name=name
        self.sequence=sequence
```

---

Comment: Please start by reading https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask-SqlAlchemy is commonly used for flask applications, otherwise just plain SqlAlchemy would should be enough.

Flask-SqlAlchemy is a wrapper over SqlAlchemy and gives you following advantages:

1. A preconfigured scoped session, engine and metadata.
2. **Model** base class which is configured declarative base.
3. **Model** base class has query attribute attached to it which can be used to query the model.
4. You don't need to remove the session at the end of your commit.

Here is how you can use your SqlAlchemy code.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\Users\\52118792\\Desktop\\test.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
user = Student("test", 123)
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you to create migrations. My tool of choice is `alembic`. To create the alembic project follow the steps as,

- `alembic init alembic`
- In alembic directory, in `env.py`, you have to assign the target metadata. It is something like `target_metadata = Base.metadata`, where Base is the declarative base for models.
- In the `env.py`, you should also import the `Student` model. So that our alembic can recognize the model changes.
- In `alembic.ini` config file, you have to provide the db path, for that assign your path `sqlite:///C:\\Users\\...\\myDB.db` to `sqlalchemy.url`.
- Once you have configured the alembic, run `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Message"`, which will detect the changes in your `Student` model, and create migrations. Run `alembic upgrade head` for applying those migrations.
- Now your `Student` table is created in sqlite, and is ready to be used.
- Create a session from the engine you have created, with something like

```
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
```

- From this `Session` factory, we can create a session object and use it to perform SQL operations.
  e.g.

```
session = Session()
students = session.query(Student).all()

for student in students:
    print(student.seq)
    print(student.name)
```

- This code will print all students.

This explanation is pretty brief, but I hope it will get you started on using sqlalchemy.

Note: I have not considered scenarios of webapps and likewise. In that case you will have to read on `scoped_session`.

For reference, you can go through this code at https://github.com/pranav93/sample_alembic_win

For alembic go through https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html